# How can I get Minecraft’s log into rsyslog?

Tags: ubuntu, minecraft, syslog

Minecraft has a log file like this:

```
2012-10-27 21:45:47 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
2012-10-27 21:45:47 [INFO] Preparing level "../worlds/world3"
2012-10-27 21:45:48 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 0
2012-10-27 21:45:49 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 16%
2012-10-27 21:45:50 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 41%
2012-10-27 21:45:51 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 75%
2012-10-27 21:45:51 [INFO] Done (4.082s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
2012-10-27 21:46:06 [INFO] foo[/12.34.56.78:50371] logged in with entity id 661 at (64.03178036049653, 76.0, -53.74201593751356)
2012-10-27 21:46:13 [WARNING] Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded?
```

Can this log file be monitored by rsyslog? It seems that the imfile module puts all the messages in one severity group and it doesn’t look like it uses the time. I’m new to syslog so maybe I’m missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it as an arbitrary file to Syslog

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` add `$ModLoad imfile`.

Then create a `minecraft.conf` file for minecraft's logs in `/etc/rsyslog.d` with the import definitions:

```
$InputFileName /mine/logs/latest.log  
$InputFileTag minecraft  
$InputFileStateFile minecraft-file1  
$InputFileSeverity info  
$InputFileFacility local7  
$InputRunFileMonitor  
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 500
```

Still playing with it to get the log cleaned up a bit